# How to divide dataframe based on month-year frame in R

Tags: r, date

I have a `dataframe` contains dates, `date` type. I want to divide the `dataframe` into  `n` different dataframe (`df1, df2, ......,dfn`) according to each month thus I can do further process on each on the month separately. noticeable that, same month of different years will be different. A loop will be nice, as there may be unlimited dates. Please give me some suggestion. I cannot understand how should I proceed.

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-05-01", "2015-05-15","2016-05-01", "2016-05-15","2016-06-02", "2016-06-12"))
names <- c("Mr A", "Ms B", "", "Ms C", "Mr K", "Mr S")
comments <- c("first comment", "", "third comment", "fourth comment", "fifth comment", "sixth comment")
like <- as.integer(c(2,4,0,6,0,3))
df <- data.frame(dates, names, comments, like, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## classification according to month, for each particular year
# df[order(as.Date(df$dates, format="%Y-%m-%d")),] # it sorts dataframe, not what I need

# df1 <- subset(df, as.Date(dates) < as.Date("2015-05-31"))
# print(df1)
# df2 <- subset(df, as.Date(dates)<as.Date("2016-05-31"))
# print(df2)
# df3 <- subset(df, as.Date(dates) < as.Date("2016-06-01"))
# print(df3)
```

e.g. first, df1 should be like this,

```
       dates names      comments like
1 2015-05-01  Mr A first comment    2
2 2015-05-15  Ms B                  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(zoo)
split(df,as.yearmon(df$dates))
$`Mai 2015`
       dates names      comments like
1 2015-05-01  Mr A first comment    2
2 2015-05-15  Ms B                  4

$`Mai 2016`
       dates names       comments like
3 2016-05-01        third comment    0
4 2016-05-15  Ms C fourth comment    6

$`Jun 2016`
       dates names      comments like
5 2016-06-02  Mr K fifth comment    0
6 2016-06-12  Mr S sixth comment    3
```

Comment: absolutely, it is the thing I was looking for. But one question, it is returning as `list`,  how to save all the different lists as data.frame?

Comment: @Noah they are data frames. Try `mylist[[1]]`

Comment: Working fine, will it be possible a loop for each of the three list save in three different dataframe automatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
a <- ymd("2015-05-01", tz = "UTC") + months(0:11)
b <- ymd("2015-05-01", tz = "UTC") + months(0:11) + days(14)
sort(c(a,b))
```